# Can I use my iPad as installation media?

Tags: boot, ipad

PC has crashed and no real access to another PC for a quick fix. If I could download the installer on my ipad and connect my ipad to my USB and boot my computer off of that..... That would be wonderful!

Answer (score 2):

The drive emulated by the Ipad does not support booting another device, sorry. Do you still have the installation media? If so, you can boot from it without altering your PC's installation until you can find out what's amiss. If not, you will need to download and prepare a LiveUSB which can be done on MacOS, Windows or Linux, whatever kind of machine you can find.

Comment: No... Well yes but Acer is a POS and the recovery CDs they had me make when I first obtained this laptop are ineffective. Windows cd isn't working... Ugh. I'm currently trying to see if I can reformat my hard drive via the bios.... Or a large rock/magnet. I have a USB drive but no way to load Ubuntu on it.